Middleware delegate does not fire for unknown file ASP.Net Core, error 404
Trying to handle file requests to change or write stream of body for some kind of file requests (not all unknown extension but some of them), by the way there are problems as below descriptions:

ASP.NET Core 8 running on IIS

Some file extensions not recognized but as a workaround need to use custom
ContentTypeProvider as shown in https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14634

Injecting a middleware like  app.UseMiddleware<MiddlewareHandler>();
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseIIS();
.
.
.
var unknownExtensionProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
unknownExtensionProvider.Mappings.Add(".UnknownExtension", "application/octed-stream");

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
                       {
                           FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(VirtualDirectories.First().PhysicalPath)),
                           RequestPath = new PathString(VirtualDirectories.First().VirtualDirctory),
                           // ContentTypeProvider = unknownExtensionProvider,//1
                           // ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,//2
                           OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                                {
                                   // code
                                }
                       });
app.UseMiddleware<MiddlewareHandler>();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
           // handle all requests
           await next();
        });



Problem #1
By uncommenting 1 and 2, the error 404 will disappear and everything works well but the InvokeAsync of MiddlewareHandler or app.Use(async (context, next) => never fired.
Problem #2
By commenting 1 and 2 the InvokeAsync or app.Use(async (context, next) => will fired nicely but error 404 occurred in client side.
Is there any way by commenting 1 and 2 but force MiddlewareHandler to Recognize unknown files in InvokeAsync something like below
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    await _next(context);
    var requestUrl = context.Request.GetEncodedPathAndQuery();

    if (requestUrl.Contains(".unknownExtension") && requestUrl.CanReplacedWithNewStream())
    {
        try
        {
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
            {
                //Some Workaround here
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            }

            await context.Response.SendFileAsync(fileInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
        }
    } 
}

Update #1:
Suppose we want implement a middleware to handle some file request with unknown extension like .exe, why by setting ServeUnknownFileTypes to true or defining ContentTypeProvider to prevent error 404 happening for StaticFile the delegate of app.Use(async (context, next) => or public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) of middleware class will not fire anymore.

Could you please tell me why you want to modify the 404 to 200? Normally, we will put the codes before the next() method to avoid the codes continue working to improve the performance.

Actually, I am looking for a way to handle File Request and change output stream by Middleware, but  as you know for unknown extensions error 404 occurred, so by setting ServeUnknownFileTypes to true error 404 will not occurred but InvokeAsync  or  the delegate of app.Use(async (context, next) => will not fired anymore.

Yes, since the UseStaticFiles is also a middleware, if it match it will directly call context.response.write before next() which makes all the next middleware will not execute.
